# Mysql query to count from A where not in B

Tags: mysql, join, count

I got a table A and a table B (and a Table C which is not really relevant). The relation is 1:n.

```
Table A
- id
- c_foreign_key

Table B
- id
- A_id
- datetime
```

Table A has about 400'000 entries, table B about 20 million.

I have a time-range, lets say from 2014/01/01 to 2014/12/31.

What i want for each month in this range is:
Count all entries from table A, grouped by c_foreign_key, where table A has no entries in table B for (month - 1.year to month).

The Result should look like this:

```
date    c_foreign_key   count(*)
--------------------------------
14/01   1               2000
14/01   2               3000
...
14/02   1               4000
14/01   2               6000
...
```

I already tried left join and "not in select" for each month the performance wasn't really good.

Comment: Show us the query that you tried, the indices that you heave and the output of EXPLAIN SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

You should debug your SQL queries with `explain` more info at [Mysql Explain Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html), also you should place `index`- es on your `datetime` fields for a better performance. Explain usualy is used to see which indexes does mysql use in your query.

Comment: I already got index set where needed. I'm struggling to do all of it in one query. What i have so far is a query for each month.